# How to get session ID for process using terminal in OS X?

Tags: macos, bash, process, terminal

I see that activity Monitor doesn't have "session ID" column as we can see in task Manager on Windows. 
How to get session ID for particular process using terminal in OS X?

Comment: What are you trying to find out/do exactly?

Comment: getting how much time user/s use applications

Comment: So you want which user is running each process?

Comment: Keep in mind that the POSIX standard has a notion of a session, but no notion of a session ID. In my experience, macOS supports sessions, but `ps` and other tools will always report session ID as `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run in terminal:

```
ps -p [process pid] -o sess=
```

Please replace `[process pid]` by your process id

Comment: This only print zeroes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248294/does-os-x-support-posix-sessions