# Does OS X support POSIX sessions?

Tags: macos, process, posix

I am working on a project which could make good use of POSIX sessions (as described [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setsid.html)) but I'm now uncertain whether I'm misunderstanding the concept and/or whether OS X even supports process sessions.

OS X 10.9 has a `setsid(2)` system call but calling it with arguments `0, 0` seems to do noting. And looking at the output of `ps -e -o pid,pgid,sess` shows that all processes have a session ID of `0`:

```
  PID  PGID   SESS
     1     1      0
    11    11      0
    12    12      0
    13    13      0
    14    14      0
    15    15      0
    16    16      0
    17    17      0
[...]
```

Does OS X support POSIX sessions for processes and, if not, is there another mechanism in place that e.g. a shell can use to send a signal to all processes started from that shell?

---

Besides looking at active processes on my system, I used the [ersatz-setsid](https://github.com/jerrykuch/ersatz-setsid) command line tool to run a process in a new session, but without success:

```
$ ./setsid sleep 1000
$ ps -eo pid,pgid,sess,command
  PID  PGID   SESS COMMAND
[...]
10650 10650      0 sleep 1000
[...]
```

Comment: It would help to see the test-program.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Updated.

Comment: I mentioned that because in POSIX it notes "this function requires that the calling process not be a process group leader".  So I would expect the test program to fork, do setsid for each forked process, and report on the various session-ids (via pipe from ps, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, Mac OSX *does* support posix sessions.  The `getsid()` system call works.  But the `ps` utility does not (`ps -o sess` produces `0` for all processes).

Answer (score 6):

As asynchronos pointed out, macOS does support the notion of POSIX sessions, but it does not have provisions for querying the session id via `ps(1)` or `top(8)`; that's why you see 0.

To add some detail:

`ps` uses `sysctl(3)` to gather up a list of running processes. That list is returned as an array of (for 64bit machines) `struct user64_kinfo_proc` (`xnu/bsd/sys/sysctl.h`). The user-land definition is `struct kinfo_proc` (`/usr/include/sys/sysctl.h`).

The kernel function that handles the filling of that array is `sysctl_prochandle()` (`xnu/bsd/kern/kern_sysctl.c`).

It, in turn, calls `fill_user64_eproc` to fill in `struct user64_eproc`, a member of `user64_kinfo_proc`.

`user64_eproc` is the data structure that (I'm guessing) *would* have a `e_psid` member denoting the session id of the given process. As such, it has no member. `fill_user64_eproc` uses the process's `struct session` to set some flags and record the process's group id into `user64_eproc`, but it doesn't record the session id because, well, there's nowhere to put it.

Interestingly, the source for `ps` has a section `ifdef`'d out that accesses `kinfo_proc.ki_sid`. This member, of course, also doesn't exist.

So, I'm sure **how** it's not returned, but not **why**, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! Sad that the `#ifdef` didn't make it into the manpage, e.g. informing the user that the version installed here can't provide the information because of kernel API restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, if you run PowerShell on macOS, its `Get-Process` command shows the session ID. It calls `getsid()` on each process to fetch it.